# Metonym Hyponym: nym relationship

Tags: semantics, lexical-relations

is there a "nym" relationship between "Ford" and "car"?

Comment: What do you think? Tell us which options you're considering and which ones you've eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

"Car" is a hyperonym and "Ford" is a hyponym of that hyperonym. It is better to speak of -onym than -nym.

Comment: Why do you say that? Which linguists use -onym? Which textbooks say that?

Comment: Because the morpheme here is -onym (< Greek  όνομα 'name'), as in the English word onomastics. There is no morpheme or allomorph *nym. https://lotsofwords.com/*onym